# Do wall-mount thermostats with remote sensors exist?

Tags: thermostat, remote-control

I read [Replacing a Honeywell Thermostat with a remote thermostat](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/103473/replacing-a-honeywell-thermostat-with-a-remote-thermostat), but the question/answer there doesn't quite fit my need.

I have a thermostat wired into the wall, but it's not in a good place. I don't want to rewire anything. Instead, what I want is a thermostat on the wall with a remote I can place wherever I want, and it signals back to control the heat. The remote just needs to sense the temperature, and be able to set a set point (although if this needed to be set on the wired wall unit, I'm okay with that).

Does this exist? I can't seem to find examples, and the search terms I use all come back with Nest or other smart thermostats, which is not what I want.

I did find an example of a two-piece unit, but one was an outlet that was switched, for controlling a space heater or the like. I might even be able to modify this to work in my application, but I'd rather go with something off-the-shelf.

Comment: I own an EcoBee thermostat with wireless temperature sensors. It works great: keeps the front room cool during the morning sun beating on the windows, and keeps the back room cool during the afternoon son.

Comment: I don't mind that this question was closed, but it was more about what kinds of options/technologies are available in general, not any particular product recommendation.

Comment: In general: Yes, available. Radio links of various kinds are the standard technology. Home-automation sensors and a HA-controllable thermostat would be another approach, requiring more setup but giving you more space for custom programming. Shop around, and come back if you have _specific_ questions about particular technology options. "What kinds" is too fuzzy to answer usefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that came to mind (I don't have one, but I have read plenty about it) is Nest. Sure enough, there is the [Nest Temperature Sensor](https://store.google.com/us/product/nest_temperature_sensor?hl=en-US)
. Little disc that you stick where you want to monitor the temperature. No display or controls. Monitored by the main Nest. $39 each, less in quantity. If you already have a Nest then this definitely makes sense. If you don't, well Nest is not the cheapest thermostat around, so you have to look at the full cost of switching.

A more basic solution, logically, is to not get as fancy as a Nest and simply have a remote sensor that the thermostat always follows (Nest lets you have the temperature adjust to different sensors at different times of the day). But to do that you need (minimum) a transmitter in the remote sensor and a receiver in the base unit, and since the typical ordinary thermostat has no radio at all, that is not something a typical "ordinary" thermostat will support because of the extra cost. So other "smart" thermostats (anything that supports WiFi access) are likely to do *something* like the Nest does, but more basic thermostats probably not.

Another example, the [Vision Pro 8000](https://amzn.to/3ehFbwv) (click image for larger view):

[image: Honeywell thermostat]

has [a $13 remote](https://amzn.to/3EkLl9W):

[image: remote]

Basically, pick a *system* of thermostat + remote based on your needs, budget and other features.